# Xpath - getting the text of label where input is checked

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am having problems getting the text of the label if the condition is the "checked" of the input checkbox within the label.

```
<label id="idUABFADYAOQA1ADcAOAA_E_label" class="radiobutton_label" onclick="" for="idUABFADYAOQA1ADcAOAA_E">
<input id="idUABFADYAOQA1ADcAOAA_E" class="radiobutton" type="radio" onclick="" checked="checked" name="PEC1"/>
Text i want to get because input is = checked
</label>

<label id="idUABFADgAOQAxADkAOAA_E_label" class="radiobutton_label" onclick="" for="idUABFADgAOQAxADkAOAA_E">
<input id="idUABFADgAOQAxADkAOAA_E" class="radiobutton" type="radio" onclick="" name="PEC1"/>
Text i do not want to get
</label>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following XPath:**

```
//input[@type='radio' and @checked = 'checked']/following-sibling::text()
```

**will return:**

```
Text i want to get because input is = checked
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath query:

```
//input[@checked="checked"]/../text()
```

Comment: Oh, I see. It is not text(), it is next-sibling... Second. Will update the post